# Disable English (automatic captions) from my uploaded videos in Youtube

Tags: video, youtube, caption, closed-captions

**How can I remove English (automatic captions) from my youtube videos?**

I have checked and couldn't find any delete option for this.

[image]

[image]

But it is still showing the subtitles.

[image]

But in some other channel, it is not displaying the subtitles. It is showing "**Subtitles/closed captions unavailable**"

[image]

Comment: is this related to video settings or user settings?

Comment: related to video settings